# OroPlatform: override oro_datetime_widget options

Tags: symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

### Context

I am actually trying to change the default placeholder for the time input of the `OroDateTimeType::class`.

[image]

I want to have, for example, the text `Horaires` instead of `Temps`.

Here is my form field in my FormType :

```php
->add('expirationDate', OroDateTimeType::class, [
    'label' => 'app.subscription.fields.expirationDate',
])
```

And in my twig view :

```
form_row(form.expirationDate)
```

### Issue

At the beginning, I have tried to used the Symfony 4 `placeholder` option for DateTime type : https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/forms/types/date.html#placeholder. It doesn't work because `OroDateTime` use a different datepicker and it override the Symfony values on load :

```
{# vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/FormBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}

{% block oro_datetime_widget %}
    {% set dateValidation = {'Date' : {}} %}
    {% set timeValidation = {'Time' : {}} %}

    {% if required %}
        {% set dateValidation = dateValidation|merge({'NotBlank' : {}}) %}
        {% set timeValidation = timeValidation|merge({'NotBlank' : {}}) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if attribute(attr, 'class') is defined %}
        {% set attrClass = attr['class'] %}
    {% else %}
        {% set attrClass = '' %}
    {% endif %}

    {% set options = {
        view: 'oroui/js/app/views/datepicker/datetimepicker-view',
        nativeMode: isMobileVersion(),
        dateInputAttrs: {
            placeholder: 'oro.form.choose_date'|trans,
            id: id,
            name: id,
            class: 'input-small datepicker-input ' ~ attrClass,
            'data-validation': dateValidation|json_encode(constant('JSON_FORCE_OBJECT')),
            'aria-live': 'assertive',
            autocomplete: 'off',
            autocorrect: 'off',
            autocapitalize: 'off'
        },
        datePickerOptions: {
            altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: years|default('-80:+1'),
            showButtonPanel: true
        },
        timeInputAttrs: {
            placeholder: 'oro.form.choose_time'|trans,
            id: 'time_selector_' ~ id,
            name: 'time_selector_' ~ id,
            class: 'input-small timepicker-input ' ~ attrClass,
            'data-validation': timeValidation|json_encode(constant('JSON_FORCE_OBJECT'))
        },
        timePickerOptions: {
        }
    } %}
    {% set id = 'hidden_' ~ id %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({
        'data-page-component-module': 'oroui/js/app/components/view-component',
        'data-page-component-options': options|json_encode(constant('JSON_FORCE_OBJECT'))
    }) %}

    {{ block('datetime_widget') }}
{% endblock oro_datetime_widget %}
```

If I change the value `timeInputAttrs.placeholder` from the `options` variable. It works.
But, I want to pass this variable to my specific form field, not globally.

### UPDATE

I finally choose to change the `oro.form.choose_time` translation in my project globally.

So, in my `Resources/translations/messages.fr_FR.yml` I've created these lines :

```yaml
oro:
  form:
    choose_time: Horaires
  auth:
    description:
      main: Baltimore
```

Then, I've understand that translations are generated in a file located in `var/cache/dev/translations/catalogue.fr_FR` :

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue;

$catalogue = new MessageCatalogue('fr_FR', array (
  'messages' => 
  array (
    'oro.form.choose_time' => 'Temps',
    'oro.auth.description.main' => 'Baltimore',
```

Here, I can see that the `oro.auth.description.main` change is applied, but the value for the key `oro.form.choose_time` is still the same.

Maybe I have a command to run ?

Comment: When you already override translations with updates from Crowdin or manual edits in UI, YAML changes will not be applied anymore. In this case, you have to write a data migration to update the loaded translations in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to override any text in the Oro application UI is to override a translation for the message used to render it. As the form placeholder is translated as well, you can use this technic. If it's the only customization you need for the form, follow [this guide](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/translations/translations/#standard-symfony-translator).

If you want to override an HTML, you can extend the template by following [the template overriding guide](https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/back-office/templates/#override-twig-templates).

But, as you want to modify the label for a single form, then the best way would be to [extend the form type](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/create_form_type_extension.html) and override the single form field with new options.

Comment: Thanks for the different methods. I have update the last part of my question with your first solution.